# Can't use package after running pipenv install

Tags: python, package-managers, pipenv

I've just installed pipenv and then run `pipenv istall pymysql` which completed successfully. However, when trying to use pymysql with `import pymysql` I get an "Unable to import 'pymysql'.

**Here's my Pipfile:**

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
pymysql = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

**And Pipfile.lock:**

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "bcb032490d492962ce66934550b641b9c4ac4c6c46efebc19592f35358039e13"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {
            "python_version": "3.7"
        },
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "pypi",
                "url": "https://pypi.org/simple",
                "verify_ssl": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "default": {
        "pymysql": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:3943fbbbc1e902f41daf7f9165519f140c4451c179380677e6a848587042561a",
                "sha256:d8c059dcd81dedb85a9f034d5e22dcb4442c0b201908bede99e306d65ea7c8e7"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==0.9.3"
        }
    },
    "develop": {}
}
```

Where does pipenv even install the packages? I can't see anything in my project folder...

Comment: Have you activated the underlying venv using `pipenv shell`?

Comment: I just tried that and nothing has changed. Does it matter if I run this after the package install?

Comment: Dunno. My personal experience with pipenv is fledgling. Give it a shot, it can't hurt. You can also look into the virtualenv `pipenv shell` created for you, and see if things are installed in site-packages. Use e.g. `python -c 'import sys;print(sys.prefix)'` to learn where things live.

Comment: Also `pipenv --venv`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was just a Visual Studio Code linting error. When running my code it works fine.

The fix was to hit `Ctrl + Shift + P` in VS Code, search for "python: select interpreter"  and change the interpreter to the python.exe in the virtualenv directory.